# How to Record Browser Content

Tags: web-browser, history

There are many ways of recording the titles and urls I have visited, but I want to record all dowloaded content, so that I can find something I have read.

Of course, the page might not exist anymore, and it might not be on the wayback machine. Or I might simply be unable to find it by searching through titles and urls only.

This will be tricky for some content, like radios, youtube, or interactive pages like gmail, but is there a browser/extension/script that offers this functionality?

To be clear: is there a way to locally record and search though everything my browser has ever displayed?

Comment: In theory, you could use a large file cache, 0 memory cache, and then copy/rsync the cache at regular intervals. But that's admittedly a hack

Comment: Sounds awesome! But how would I view old pages?

Comment: Good question. The obvious answer would be to copy the saved files back to where your browser keeps its cache and do "about:cache" but I suspect that might not work. The individual files would have the data you wanted, but it would be pretty ugly. Another ugly approach would be to capture all network traffic and store it somewhere.

Comment: One solution could be to run a GreaseMonkey script every time a page is loaded to save it (complete page with html and content), and timestamp the pages. These could then be opened offline, and searched through with grep. Better solutions welcome.

Comment: Another attractive option is to let Chrome do the work, as per [this](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/load-cached-pages-when-offline-in-chrome/) 2015 article.

Comment: @MrMartin please note this site is about recommending **software** – not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), ideas or approaches. I've hence converted your answers to comments, as none of the two were recommending an existing specific and ready-to-use software meeting the requirements.

Comment: @Izzy This question was moved from Web Applications to Software Recommendations for exactly this reason. Surely using Chrome with a plugin is ready-to-use software, right?

Comment: Technically, I'm the one breaking the rules since I'm offering non-software solustions

Comment: @MrMartin If it would be complete, yes. But just saying "a Greasemonkey script" without the script being in existence is an approach. Even if one installs Greasemonkey, the script is still missing. So this is close to "one could write a software doing that" – unless the script is included.